# The counterpart of the industrial policy for the service sector?

Tags: policy, industrial-policy

I am reading book https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-319-39070-3 about the industrial policy in the EU that is aiming for the industrial and manufacturing sector. I am now seeking the similar term or concepts for the governing and supporting of the service sector (which is becoming more important with each year)? What is this term and concepts? "Service policy" means something very different as can be seen by the results of the Google. Many countries (e.g. Sweden, UK, Germany) are releasing their industrial policy documents and strategies. Are there similar planning and governance for the service sector as well and how such policy/governance is named?

Comment: "Industrial" in "Industrial policy" uses the term "Industry" in the sense of a major sector of the economy, something that includes service producing industries. An "industrial policy" is a policy to governmentally favor some particular industry sector over another. No new term in necessary.

Comment: "Service sector policy" might be an obvious name. Did you check for it?

Comment: There are often policies for specific service sectors like the arts, tourism, and finance.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, it falls on the category of digital policy, since digital is now considered the big thing that is changing everything and the EU is acting as an experimental regulator in that sense, setting the trend. Moreover, there is a political will to move economic transactions and activities online, so that it is possible to reduce tax evasion and illegal activities, and this is considered a priority for some member states. Of course, since the EU is not a federal state yet, each member has its own strategy and regulation, as well as some smaller administrative entities (such as regions, counties, municipalities).